# Reread partition table without rebooting?

Tags: partition, fdisk, linux

Sometimes, when resizing or otherwise mucking about with partitions on a disk, cfdisk will say:

> `Wrote partition table, but re-read table failed.  Reboot to update table.`

(This also happens with other partitioning tools, so I'm thinking this is a Linux issue rather than a cfdisk issue.) Why is this, and why does it only happens *sometimes*, and what can I do to avoid it?

Note: Please assume that none of the partitions I am actually editing are opened, mounted or otherwise in use.

---

Update:

cfdisk uses `ioctl(fd, BLKRRPART, NULL)` to tell Linux to reread the partition table.  Two of the other tools recommended so far (`hdparm -z` *`DEVICE`*, `sfdisk -R` *`DEVICE`*) does exactly the same thing. The `partprobe` *`DEVICE`* command, on the other hand, seems to use a new ioctl called BLKPG, which might be better; I don't know.  (It also falls back on BLKRRPART if BLKPG fails.)

BLKPG seems to be a "this partition has changed; here is the new size" operation, and it looked like `partprobe` called it individually on all the partitions on the device passed, so it should work if the individual partitions are unused.  However, I have not had the opportunity to try it.

Comment: `man sfdisk` says: `Since version 2.26 sfdisk no longer provides the -R or --re-read option to force the kernel to reread the partition table.  Use blockdev --rereadpt instead.`

Comment: Check for a running software raid! Maybe `mdadm --stop /dev/mdXX` is needed first?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

IMHO the most reliable/best answer is

```
partprobe /dev/sdX
```

Comment: I just expanded a dev under Ubuntu Server, this dev is a hardware raid. After expanding the underlying raid using the raidcontroller, I dismounted the filesystem and tried "partprobe /dev/sda" - this did not work. "fdisk -l" still showed the old size. I then ran "hdparm -z /dev/sda" and this did the trick. I could then mount and resize my filesystem with no reboot. I know I'm not adding anything really other than YMMV.

Comment: i'm on centos 6.5 ; kernel 2.6.32 . all the following commands did not make kernel reread partition :
- partprobe /dev/sda   (warnikg : kernel failed to reread)

Comment: @Max, I've also noticed that sometimes even partprobe prints out an error that it didn't work. Sometimes a reboot is the only option to be certain.  Many times it does seem to work for me though.

Comment: This did not work for me because there were some directories still mounted with --bind. The partition itself was already unmounted but the bind-mounts pointing to that partition were still there. Strange that umount worked and partprobe not, but after umounting the bind-mounts too, I could also partprobe the disk.

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS 6 after flagellating around with `kpartx` and `udevadm trigger` for 10 minutes.  Thank you!

Comment: This works even if the device is mounted. Nice! This enabled me to resize a cloud disk, then repartition and resize the ext4 partition on it without interrupting a data import process.

Comment: This doesn't work if some sdX partition is part of a [started software RAID array](https://serverfault.com/a/940531/63769) (tested under 4.18.18-300.fc29.x86_64).

Answer (score 24):

Rereading partition table information doesn't always work, but try

```
hdparm -z /dev/sda
```

or

```
sfdisk -R /dev/sda
```

If it works the values in  /proc/partitions will change.

Comment: hdparm worked for me.

Comment: the sfdisk -R option doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be noted that `hdparm` command will only work if partitions are not mounted.

Comment: ...indeed, it looks like `sfdisk -R` was removed somewhere between util-linux 2.24.2 and 2.26.1

Comment: `man sfdisk` says: `Since version 2.26 sfdisk no longer provides the -R or --re-read option to force the kernel to reread the partition table.  Use blockdev --rereadpt instead.`

Comment: I'm getting `blockdev: ioctl error on BLKRRPART: Invalid argument` but it may be because I'm trying it on a partition in use on a VMware image.  Out of my depth here ...

Answer (score 18):

I (the original questioner) had a situation a few days ago when none of the other answers (including `partprobe /dev/sdX`, currently the accepted and highest-voted answer) worked.  What **did** work, however, was this:

```
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdX
```

(I don't know why this worked and the others didn't, but I'm happy it did work, as it saved me a reboot on a busy server.)

Answer (score 15):

**On Centos7 :**

*According to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/199573*

You should try :

```
partx -u <partition>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: That was the only one that work for me. Thank you so much for sharing!! Top of the day to you, sir!

Answer (score 8):

> Note: Please assume that none of the partitions I am actually editing
>   are opened, mounted or otherwise in use.

Given that assumption, the partition table *can* be successfully rescanned, and the issue won't arise.  If you're getting that error, it's because the partition table *is* currently in use, and hence can't be re-scanned without creating inconsistencies.

Comment: Some partitions might be in use, but none of them are the ones that I am actually changing, though they might be in the same partition table.

Comment: The kernel isn't that smart.  If any partition in the table is in use, the kernel doesn't rescan.  Getting that wrong in the other direction could be catastrophic, so it's being safe.  If you want to stuff around with partitions at will, use LVM.

Answer (score 7):

When a command like `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdX` fails with

```
blockdev: ioctl error on BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
```

this usually means that some (old) partition is indeed still somehow used by the kernel.

Possible causes/fixes:

1. an sdX partition - say `sdX1` -  is still mounted - check with `mount` and umount it
2. `/dev/sdX1` is part of a software raid - check `cat /proc/mdstat` and possibly stop the relevant arrays, e.g. `mdadm --stop /dev/md126`
3. `/dev/sdX1` is part of an LVM physical volume - check with `pvdisplay`/`vgdisplay` and possibly deactivate with `vgchange`
4. `/dev/sdX1` is part of some device mapping - e.g. via `cryptsetup` - check `/dev/mapper` and `lsblk` and possibly remove the mapping (e.g. `cryptsetup luksClose`)
5. Race condition with some udev probing - check running processes with `ps` and possibly kill one

If one tool - say `blockdev --rereadpt` fails usually similar ones like (`partx -uv`, `kpartx`, `partprobe`, `kpartprobe`) fail in a similar way until the root cause is eliminated.

Answer (score 6):

It is not based on partition that you are editing.

Suppose you have only one harddisk (`/dev/sda`) and two partitions (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`) and you have mounted only one partition (`/dev/sda1`). If you delete or change anything about other partition which is not even mounted (`/dev/sda2`) you will get the error that re-reading of partition table failed and kernel will use old table.

But if you have two harddisks (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`) and none of the partitions of (`/dev/sdb`) are in use. Then you can add / delete / resize /edit partitions of `/dev/sdb` and they will be re-read without any problem. But even if one partition of /dev/sdb was mounted during change. Then kernel will keep using old table.

Answer (score 5):

With all mount points unmounted, running Yocto 2.4:

```
partprobe /dev/sda
```

Still failed to re-load the partition table after partitions had been deleted on the device. Also tried -- and failed were:

```
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=block; udevadm settle
hdparm -z /dev/sda
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda
```

All reported similar "BLKRRPART failed : device or resource busy..." errors instructing me to reboot. Is this failure of previously working methods possibly due to the fact that udev is now under systemd control? Thinking along those lines I tried:

```
systemctl restart systemd-udevd.service
```

And suddenly my disk is available again, **without a reboot!**

Comment: The top accepted answer is incomplete: in the modern `systemd` world, THIS is the correct answer. Please note you also need to restart one of those (or both) `systemd-udev-settle` and `systemd-udev-trigger`. Restarting just `systemd-udevd` like Camp said was not enough for me. But restarting also the other two did the trick!

Comment: `systemctl restart systemd-udev*` worked for me (although it printed a lot of warnings).

Answer (score 4):

i'm on centos 6.5 x64 ; kernel 2.6.32 . and i'm testing the fdisk trick to resize.

```
/dev/sda1 /boot
/dev/sda2 /
```

All the following commands did ***not*** make kernel reread partition :

- **partprobe /dev/sda**   (warning : kernel failed to reread ....)
- **hdparm -z /dev/sda** (BLKRRPART failed : device or resource busy)
- **blockdev -rereadpt /dev/sda** (BLKRRPART failed : device or resource busy)
- **sfdisk -R /dev/sda** (BLKRRPART failed : device or resource busy)

i still need a reboot to make it work

Comment: none of that worked for me either (proxmox VM, centos 7, xfs partition, no lvm). @uus answer did work, though: http://serverfault.com/a/722386/102252

Comment: All the above commands did not work for me either.

Comment: I think kernel 2.6.32 has issue, I used these before on other machines, it worked just fine, even when adding partitions with higher numbers between older partitions. i.e. sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 - delete sdb2 , then sdb1 sdb4 sdb5 sdb3. In addition to above, partx, kpartx, blockdev didn't work as well.

Comment: I don't think that it's unusual that if one command fails rereading the partitions, all fail - [see also my answer for how to eliminate some causes for this](https://serverfault.com/a/940531/63769).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/rescan
```

(But might not work, see the comment below)

Comment: This does not reread the partition table. It just updates the geometry information, cache mode, etc. SCSI IDENTIFY_DRIVE is being issued.

Comment: This is the only solution, that helped me on vmware vm.

Comment: @user3132194, I assume you'd just resized the drive? Then you need to rescan the device, not reread the partition table. They're two completely different operations, and only the partition table reread is the one that's on-topic for this question.

Answer (score 2):

in Alpine-Linux netboot mode ,
new partitions were shown in dmesg,
main disks /dev/sda were present
but no /dev/sdaX partition device files ,
tried all tricks above ,
finally

```
mknod -m 660 ${chroot_dir}/dev/sda1 b 8 1
mknod -m 660 ${chroot_dir}/dev/sda2 b 8 2
```

worked

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_in_a_chroot

Comment: 666 on a device node is.. not particularly wise. You don't want non-administrative users going straight to the underlying block device to bypass file permissions.

Comment: fixed... 660 now ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me neither `partprobe` or `blockdev` solution worked. Although, this one works:

```
udevadm settle --exit-if-exists=/dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue in Alpine Linux (not chrooted) where partprobe did nothing. It was using mdev to manage the /dev and /sys mounts, and so `mdev -s` to trigger a re-scan after imaging the mmcblk0 device worked.

Answer (score 0):

`kpartx -a <partition>` can be run  two times on newly created partition .... instead of rebooting the system.

Comment: *Two* times?  Do you also run “`sync; sync; sync`”? ☺ I smell superstition…

Comment: I think this superstition came from the fact that you check if your sync, by doing a second sync.   Except that the second one is only valuable for the operator, to confirm it returns to prompt immediately, thus indicating the first sync completed as expected. 

a few blogs and tutorials later, and ....

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check udev service is running. This is especially useful when partprobe, hdparm, blockdev, and various other commands do not seem to make any difference what device files are available in /dev/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
fdisk /dev/sdX
```

and exit by "w"

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to ask kernel to "reread partition table", or update the size of specific partition to its actual size on Oracle Linux 6, these instructions could be helpful.

Let's say you have a machine with Oracle Linux 6, relatively new kernel 4.1.12-124.28.3.el6uek.x86_64, you just changed the size of your virtual disk, and now you're in situation that your /dev/sdc is 2.1 TiB but its own only **MOUNTED** partition sdc1 is 2 TiB, and you want to resize it to 2.1 TiB without unmounting it or rebooting. `lsblk` will show you something like that:

```
sdc                              8:32   0  2.1T  0 disk
`-sdc1                           8:33   0    2T  0 part
```

What I've found is that there is no ready-to-use application that you can install from package repository to help you with the issue: all programs in repository are too old and in the best case they will rewrite your partition table to disk (it's still required), but will use BLKRRPART to notify kernel about changes that won't work with mounted/"busy" partitions.

What you can do instead is to build your own simple C program that will run newer BLKPG ioctl to do the trick. Fortunately, you don't need to write it from scratch: just download [this C file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gportay/blkpg-part/master/blkpg-part.c), modify it, build and run:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gportay/blkpg-part/master/blkpg-part.c
sed -i 's/BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION/3/' blkpg-part.c
make blkpg-part
```

Why you need to replace BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION with hardcoded value 3? It's because Oracle Linux 6 ships with the old conservative UAPI that is not synchronized with actual Linux kernel API, and therefore `BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION` constant from include/uapi/linux/blkkg.h is not available, even though the feature is present in kernel (you can check it by grepping the [Linux kernel source code](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/UEKR4/archive/x86_64/getPackageSource/kernel-uek-4.1.12-124.28.3.el6uek.src.rpm) with `BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION`).

Okay, so you have your `blkpg-part` built, now you can check that it's working. Let's start with running it "dry-run": just ask it to resize the partition /dev/sdc1 with its own current size (reminder: the size of partition from kernel's point of view is still the "old" one, therefore /sys/class/block/sdc1/size will return the "old" size, not the one that is written in the new partition table):

```
./blkpg-part resize /dev/sdc 1 $(( $(cat /sys/class/block/sdc1/start) * 512 )) $(( $(cat /sys/class/block/sdc1/size) * 512 ))
```

If it runs without errors, it means that this userspace application succeeded with running `BLKPG_RESIZE_PARTITION` and interacting with kernel; so, we are close to actually ask kernel to change the size of the partition.

Now you need to run blkpg-part with the new partition size in bytes that is written in the new partition table. `parted /dev/sdc unit B print` can be used to identify the actual size of the partition, you'll get something like that:

```
Number  Start   End             Size            File system  Name     Flags
 1      20480B  2254857813503B  2254857793024B               primary  lvm
```

So, the new size of partition is 2254857793024, and you can finally run this command below:

```
./blkpkg-part3 resize /dev/sdc 1 $(( $(cat /sys/class/block/sdc1/start) * 512 )) 2254857793024
```

Immediately after that kernel will update the state of the partition, and in lsblk you'll see:

```
sdc                              8:32   0  2.1T  0 disk
`-sdc1                           8:33   0  2.1T  0 part
```

*Useful links*:

- [[V4] block: Support online resize of disk partitions](https://lwn.net/Articles/506063/)
- [resizepart from util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/disk-utils/resizepart.c#L68)
- [block: add partition resize function to blkpg ioctl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c83f6bf98dc1f1a194118b3830706cebbebda8c4)

Answer (score -5):

If you read the manpage for 'man oracleasm-scandisks' you will note the text below.  oracleasm is using /proc/partitions as the source of all scanning it performs.  You must get your raw devices listed in /proc/partitions before you can do a scandisk.  The Scanorder and Scanexclude parameters you place in /etc/sysconfig/oracleasm relate to the names found in /proc/partitions (!!!!).

---------- man oracleasm-scandisks ------
...

HOW SCANNING HAPPENS
       The scan proceeds in four basic stages.

```
   First, the list of disks to scan is created. If disks were specified on the command line, this is the list.
   If not, /proc/partitions is read, and each block device is added, subject to the -o and -x options.

   Second, the partition tables of each disk in the scan are reloaded unless the -s option was specified. Any
   disks that no longer exist are dropped.

   Third, the list of disks is recreated based on the new partition tables.

   Finally, each disk in the list is checked to see if it is marked for ASM use. Disks that are marked are
   instantiated.
```

Comment: ...he's mentioned nothing about using `oracleasm-scandisks`

Comment: This is a separate piece of (Oracle-provided) software that's _reading_ `/proc/partitions`. The goal of this question is how to tell _the kernel itself_ to update the data it uses to _generate_ `/proc/partitions`.