# Mount new partition on a removable disk after dd?

Tags: linux, mount, dd

How do I mount a new partition on a removable disk after dd without removing and re-inserting the device?

If I use dd to write an image to a removable device, such as a usb-stick or an sd-card, the partitions on the device might change. When I use "fdisk -l" to list the partitions, the new ones are clearly visible. However, they are not visible when doing "cat /proc/partitions" and I can't mount any of the new partitions.

If I remove and re-insert the device, the partitions are "refreshed" and show up in /proc/partitions. Now it is possible to mount the new partitions. How do I trigger this refresh from a shell prompt without having to remove and re-insert the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have *parted* installed or can install it, you'll get *partprobe*.  Use it like:

```
partprobe /dev/sdX
```

See:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/re-read-the-partition-table-without-rebooting-linux-system.html
[Reread partition table without rebooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting)