# linux /dev/sd? read failed

Tags: linux, device, remove, failed

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, so I'm posting this in the hope it helps someone else...

My scenario was linux system with an external drive that was connected (and mounted) was suddenly disconnected.  I'm not sure why- it may have been a power issue.

After that linux continually reported:

```
/dev/sdd: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
```

when running `fdisk -l`, or `pvscan`, or `vgscan` or `lvscan` etc.

Reconnecting the drive did not work, and there was now no way to remount the drive.

What I needed to do was delete the /dev/sdd device.

```
pvremove --force /dev/sdd
```

removed the device from LVM, but did not stop the error.

**Here's the solution**:

```
cd /sys/block/sdd/device
echo 1 > delete
```

An answer [**here**](https://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting/217156#217156) pointed me to look in the right place. kudos to bogdano

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it when you are able to.

Comment: Answer:  cd /sys/block/sdd/device
    echo 1 > delete

An answer here pointed me to look in the right place. kudos to bogdano