# Is reboot necessary after expanding a disk/partition?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition

I'm running a virtual machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) on VMware ESXi. The virtual machines needed extra storage as to why i raised the disk size in ESXi, and ran pationing etc. from the virtual machine itself. All was fine (i thought) as both the `df -h` and `df -i` reported lots of diskspace and inodes left. But when i hit the partition's old limit i was faced by "no space left on device". As the case was very urgent i decided to reboot the machine which solved the problem and let new data be written to the partition.

My question: Is reboot of the virtual machine necessary or could it be avoided somehow?

**Quick summary**:

- Raise disk size in ESXi
- Repartition using `parted`
- Grow filesystem (xfs)
- Verify with `df`

Comment: Looks like you had to? I don't understand whether your observations already answered your question. I thought XFS can be expanded live therefore, suggesting theres's no need for reboot.

Comment: @Recct Thank you for replying. What i wanted to know, was if any command could help me avoid a reboot. The case could aswel be that i missed something along the way growing the filesystem/partition?

Comment: When you resize a partition, [this](http://serverfault.com/q/36038/126632) often happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `partprobe /dev/sdX`  or `hdparm -z /dev/sdX`

Anyway, in some circumstances these command are not sufficient, and a reboot is required.

In your case, the strange thing is that a filesystem resize was performed without problem (and confirmed by a `df`, right?) and so the partition table should have been reread correctly...

Comment: Thanks shodanshok. Yep, no error messages etc., all went fine resizing the partition. I'm not able to test this scenario, but after researching a bit on partprobe I seem to come up with the same conclusion as you. Thank you for clearing up this little mystery.