# Reload partition table on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, partition, truenas

I'm searching for a way to reload a partition table in FreeBSD 12 (FreeNAS).
I don't have `hdparm` nor `gfdisk` nor `partprobe`.

What's the standard way of doing ?

PS: my `pkg` doesn't work behind a firewall so i probably can't install packages other than  via SCP.
[EDIT]Got my firewall rules relaxed, I can install packages if needed[/EDIT]

Already read [Reread partition table without rebooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting) but there are only solutions for linux.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to reload partition table information manually on FreeBSD. Anyways, `man gpart`.

Comment: Indeed, as long as geom can read something. After zeroing the disk, geom didn't "see" the disk so gpart couldn't create new partitions unless I reboot.

Comment: Hum? When I `dd` by USB stick with zeroes, geom automatically detects it and removes all partition information from `gpart` output, as well as partition character devices from `/dev/`.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, `glabel refresh /dev/your/disk` will help. In practice, in my case, it did not help.